# Decimal positions in result c#

Tags: c#, math, datagridview, double

I have got this code which calculates the summary of 2 multiplied columns of all rows in datagridview.

```
private void vypocti_odvody(int price, int vat, int tot_rows2)
    {
        try
        {
            double outVal = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)

            {
                outVal = outVal + (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[price].Value)/100) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[vat].Value) + (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[price].Value));
            }

         //   s_ub_celk.Text = (((a / 100) * b) + a).ToString();
            Convert.ToDecimal ( result.Text = outVal.ToString()) ;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Chybové hlášení K3 " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }


    }
```

How can I improve decimal positions? Now the result is like: 123,5484250 I would like to have only 2 decimal positions with result for example 123,55.

Sorry for my poor english I hope 'decimal position' is express for word that I really mean. In case I made an example for better understanding.

Thank you everyone for your time, comments and answers.

Comment: Usually there is a `Format` property somewhere which you could set to `0.00`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a format string to convert the text:

```
result.Text = outVal.ToString("0.00");
```

See [this list](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/) for more ways on how to format numbers. You can also use

```
result.Text = string.Format("{0:0.00}", outVal);
```

which is exactly the same as the code above.

Comment: Why working with string format on double and when you know that string.format is truncated the number.

Comment: @3wic: "0.00" will round the number to the 2nd decimal place. In your solution you might still get a different result because of floating point errors, whereas `string.Format` works on the string representation itself and not the number.

Comment: @3wic: See [this ideone](http://ideone.com/YzGX2z) for the OP's example with rounding.

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using `DataGridView` you can set the format of the cell like

```
DataGridView1.Columns[required column index or name].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Math.Round(value, digits)`

The value is your result and digits is how many decimal you want

Answer (score 1):

Use System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo to control settings.

```
System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo numberFormatInfo = new System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo();           
numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;

decimal decimalexample = 123.5484250M;

string decimalasstring = decimalexample.ToString(numberFormatInfo);
```

Regards.